# how to move git repositories from Windows to Ubuntu server?

Tags: git, gitweb

I have published several git repositories in an Apache http server located in a Windows system. And the files are saved in the same computer. Now I want to move these git repositories into another   computer, where there is also an Apache http server with gitweb. Generally I use `git clone http://username@ipaddress/git/repository_name` to clone these repositories into other local machines.

But when I directly copied these git repositories into one git root directory, the `git clone` will report one error about `info/refs`.

Is there any efficient ways to do this work? Thank you.

**UPDATED:**

In the Windows 7 computer, I save these repositories in `F:/gitroot` directory. And in the `httpd.conf`, the related configuration is as follows:

```
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT F:/gitroot
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    ScriptAlias /git/ "D:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"

    <Directory "D:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/">
    Allow From All
    </Directory>

    <Directory "F:/gitroot">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 192.168.0.0/24
    Allow From 127.0.0.1
    Allow From All
    </Directory>

    <Location /git >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git repository"
    AuthUserFile F:/gitroot/htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

And for clarity, I make a new directory named `test` in `F:/gitroot`, then go into the `test` directory, `git init --bare`, then we could initialize a new git repository. Then in other computers, we could use `git clone http://username@windows_ipaddress/git/test` to clone this repository to develop. Also we could use `git push/pull origin master` to do those operations about git to update or modifiy the git repository.

Now, I want to move these repositories in `F:/gitroot` into another computer where the operating system is `Ubuntu 12.04`, and also the apache server is installed and configured with gitweb for http access like that in the Windows system. I just copy those files in `F:/gitroot` into `/media/backup_data/gitroot` the Ubuntu computer. The structure of these git repositories is not changed.

When I use `git clone http://username@ubuntu_ipaddress/git/test`, the error is :

```
    Cloning into 'test'...
    fatal: http://192.168.0.2/git/test/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Finally, I have found the answer: we should change the privileges of the copied directory.

```
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data test
```

Then, the `git clone` will be executed successfully.

Comment: Do you mean that you normally use `git clone` but this time just did a file system copy of the gits? Please include the full error message from Git.

Comment: @MagnusBäck, thank you for replying! I have found the causes and updated the post, please kindly check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this question in the Section `UPDATE` of the original post.